# scala joinWithCassandraTable result to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Datastax spark-Cassandra-connector to access some data in Cassandra.
My requirement is to Join an RDD with a Cassandra table, fetch the result and store it in the hive table.

Im using joinWithCassandraTable to join the cassadra table. After the join the resuting RDD looks like below

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row, 
com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = 
CassandraJoinRDD[17] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19
```

I tried below steps to convert to the data frame but none of the approaches is working.

```scala
val data=joinWithRDD.map{
   case(_, cassandraRow) =>    Row(cassandraRow.columnValues:_*)
}

sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

I'm getting below error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field 
   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of 
   type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

Can you please help me in converting `joinWithCassandraTable` to a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you're using dataframe on the left side of the join. Instead of using `joinWithCassandraTable` that uses RDD API, I recommend to take the Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.x (2.5.1 is the latest) that [has support for join in the Dataframe API](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all), and use it directly. It's really easy, you just need to start your job with `--conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions` to activate this [functionality](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#special-cassandra-catalyst-rules-since-scc-25), after that, code is just using normal joins on dataframes:

```scala
val parsed = ...some dataframe...
val cassandra = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "stock_info", "keyspace" -> "test"))
  .load

// we can use left join to detect what data is incorrect - if we don't have some data in the
// Cassandra, then symbol field will be null, so we can detect such entries, and do something with that
// we can omit the joinType parameter, in that case, we'll process only data that are in the Cassandra
val joined = parsed.join(cassandra, cassandra("symbol") === parsed("ticker"), "left")
   .drop("ticker")
```

Full source code with README is [here](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/tree/master/cassandra-join-spark).

Comment: To use Spark Cassandra 2.5x I need the spark version 2.4 and above. But I'm using spark2.3 so can't use this feature. I want to play around with joinWithCassandraTable result. What's the best way to convert this rdd into dataframe?

Comment: I just tested 2.5.1 with Spark 2.3.2, and it worked fine - I've got `Cassandra Direct Join` in the output... If it wont work for you, then let's try to do it other way. Maybe you just can define a case class for your table data, and use `joinWithCassandraTable[CaseClass](...`

Comment: Thanks, Alex: after using case class my result looks like.  com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,String] = CassandraJoinRDD[86] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19       here I selected only one column  from casandra table. I have almost 100 columns.       ex: Array[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, String)] = Array(([123456],F2))    . how can I convert into dataframe ? Or is there any easy way to extarct each column value and store into a hive table?

Comment: you need to convert it into flat RDD via `.map` (better into case class), and then convert RDD to dataframe

Comment: Sorry..I might be missing some basic stuff.  Thsi is my RDD looks like  aftet using  joinWithCassandraTable. Array[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow)] = Array(([234567],CassandraRow{event: gg})).  This is how im flatting the RDD  .val data=joinWithRDD_take.map{case(_, cassandraRowa) => Row(cassandraRowa.columnValues:_*)}
case class schema(sv_event_type: String)
val data2=sqlContext.createDataFrame(data.map{case Row(sv_event_type: String) => schema(sv_event_type.trim) }) .  But this is not working. Can you please help in flat the RDD?

Comment: How to do partitonby replica using dataframe api ?